Docusign EnvelopesApi.ListDocuments fails with NOT FOUND
I am getting "File or directory not found" 404 on each envelopeid I try to call with ListDocuments.  The envelopeId's do exist and can be viewed on docusign's site.
```
AuthUtil auth = new AuthUtil(_keyVaultConfiguration);
OAuth.OAuthToken token = auth.GetTokenFromJwt();
Account account = auth.GetAccountInfo(token);

DocuSignClient docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(account.BaseUri);
docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);

// known good envelopeId
Envelope envvelope = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(account.AccountId, eml.TEnvelopeId);

foreach (EnvelopeDocument doc in envelope.EnvelopeDocuments)...


Code throws the 404 before the foreach is reached.

What would cause this?

** Solved:  It turns out a proxy service , on my side somewhere was removing the auth header!  I am working with IT..


Updated, seeing same result, not found.

If you want information for a specific envelope use Envelopes:get not :list.
Envelopes:list takes an optional request object and query parameters. Use the eSign request logging feature to see what you're actually sending in your Envelopes:list API call. -- You're not calling it correctly

I enabled logs, I am not seeing any that look like they relate to the requests I am making, what am I looking for?

So, after careful study of the logs it seems my api calls are not logging.  We only have one prod account, where are they going?

To see your API client's log, login to the web app with the same user id used. By the API app
